# Remove documents with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I work on several log files that I process with logstash. I divide them into several documents (multiline) and then I extract the information I want.

The problem is that I find myself in the end with several documents where I have nothing interesting and that takes me up space.

Do you know a way to delete documents where there is no information extract by logstash ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In lower versions of ElasticSearch, when creating indexes you can specify a ttl field that indicates the expiry of a document in the index. You could set the ttl to a value of say 24 hours. [Read more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-ttl-field.html)

However ttl has been deprecated as of version 2.0 since its a clumsy way of removing stale data, personally, i create rolling indexes with logstash and have a cron job that simply drops the daily index at eod via curl.

Also refer to this article from ES

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html